# How to load the App.config file?

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

I'm parsing the App.config file of a project. This config file has been loaded from a caller project. Inside the called project, I have something like:

```
   XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
   xmlDoc.Load("app.config");
   // Some parsing...
```

Unfortunately the app.config file is not correctly located. Apparently the Load method is browsing the ~/bin/Release directory of the caller project, but the app.config file is located in the ~ directory.

Is there any way I can load this App.config file correctly?

Thanks

Comment: Is this a forms project? I'm guessing it is...

Comment: Why don't you just use ConfigurationManager from System.Configuration (you need to add a reference to that!) and you're done - no messy parsing yourself.....

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't understand why you need to do this. The configuration file `App.Config` is copied to the runtime directory at build time and renamed `yourapplicationname.exe.config`.

You can use the [`ConfigurationManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) class to access the contents of that file.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to load configuration information is to use the types in the `System.Configuration` namespace. Don't parse it yourself. For many of the types you'll need to also reference `System.Configuration.dll`.

Visual Studio should copy a file called `app.config` to the output directory when you build. It *renames* the file to `<assembly_name>.config`, so if you assembly is `myapp.exe`, then the config file will be `myapp.exe.config`. Check the properties of the file are set to "Build Action: None, Copy to output directory: do not copy". VS treats this as a special case. Don't override it.

Comment: I didn't use ConfigurationManager because I didn't find how to parse my app.config file with it. How can I access to methods like: SelectNodes or GetNamedItem etc..?

Comment: I've yet to find a good introductory (i.e. simple) example of custom sections and parsing them -- it is fairly easy once you know how. Must add to the blog to do list :-)

Comment: Thanks Richard!
FYI I moved my second question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804390/how-to-parse-app-config-using-configurationmanager