# How to parse app.config using ConfigurationManager?

Tags: c#, app-config, configurationmanager

I was using a certain method for parsing my app.config file. Then I was told that using ConfigurationManager is better and simpler. But the thing is I don't know how to do it with ConfigurationManager.

My original code looked like this:

```
   XmlNode xmlProvidersNode;
    XmlNodeList xmlProvidersList;
    XmlNodeList xmlTaskFactoriesList;

    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load("app.config");
    xmlProvidersNode = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("TaskProviders");
    xmlProvidersList = xmlProvidersNode.SelectNodes("TaskProvider");

    foreach (XmlNode xmlProviderElement in xmlProvidersList)
    {
        if (xmlProviderElement.Attributes.GetNamedItem("Name").Value.Equals(_taskProvider))
        {
            xmlTaskFactoriesList = xmlProviderElement.SelectNodes("TaskTypeFactory");
            foreach (XmlNode xmlTaskFactoryElement in xmlTaskFactoriesList)
            {
                if (xmlTaskFactoryElement.Attributes.GetNamedItem("TaskType").Value.Equals(_taskType))
                {
                    taskTypeFactory = xmlTaskFactoryElement.Attributes.GetNamedItem("Class").Value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What would be the equivalent using ConfigurationManager? (Because all I can see is how to get keys not nodes..)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a class that inherits `ConfigurationSection` called, say, `MyConfigSection`. Then you can use the `ConfigurationManager.GetSection` method to get an instance of your `MyConfigSection` class. The `ConfigurationManager` will do all the parsing, so you will have a strongly typed object to work with. [Here is an excellent example to follow.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: And you said it was simpler!

Thank you for the link, I'll read it.

Comment: @Amokrane, it may not be simpler the first time you use it, but I generally find that is it a good practice to work *with* the framework and not invent your own half-baked solutions to problems that have already been solved by people in Redmond WA ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If you are concerned about the custom sections create your own class using Configuration section class. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx) is an example about using it.